# Python: Case Sensitivity in user input

Tags: python

I want to make my user's input (in Python) case insensitive. Like if user type admin, Admin ADMIN or even he or she types like aDMIN. This should be insensitive so i can get exact input

Comment: Just use `.lower()` on the user input to ensure it will always be in lower case.

Answer (score 1):

Use lower() : `s = input().lower()`

Answer (score 1):

Convert your user's input to lower case. Then whatever you compare it to can be lower case.

```
string = input("Enter something: ") 
string = string.lower()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `lower()` function, it converts a string to lower case.

```
myStr = JAMES
myStr.lower() > james
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just compare it to lower case admin every time.

```py
input_str = input("Enter role: ")

if input_str.lower() == "admin":
   pass
```